# How to recall variables made in if() functions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, double

This is going to be quite hard to explain, but bear with me:

Say, for example, I have an if statement that does the following, would it be possible to use the variable `x2` outside of this if statement:

```
int x = 3

if(x>2.5) {
    String x2 = "X =" + Double.toString(x);
}

//How do I use the x2 outside the if function?
System.out.println(x2);
```

Every time I try to do it, the Eclipse underlines it and says the variable has not been defined, which I gather is because `x2` might not be created if `x<=2.5`, so nothing would be outputted.

The reason I ask this is because I am trying to make a program that emails me a set of variables if (condition is `true`).

But instead of putting the code for emailing the data to me inside of the if statement (I have about 20), and get 20 different emails if the condition is true, I want to be able to put the email code outside of this, so that all 20 variables will be sent in ONE email, if the condition is true for all of them.

I hope that makes sense; if you have any questions just drop a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have to declare it before the if block in order to use it after it.

```
String x2 = null;
if(x>2.5){
    x2 = "X =" + Double.toString(x);
}

System.out.println(x2);
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, will make answer when it lets me

Comment: Is it a good idea to print `"null"` if `x` is smaller than `2.5`?

Comment: @Tom I had to initialize it with something, and since I don't know the specific use case, I went with null.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use a variable that has been declared outside of the block that it was declared in, **but** you can use the object. Reference variables and objects are different beasts. Though your problem has nothing to do with this, and in your case, I'd simply declare the variable before the loop:

```
int x = 3
String x2 = "";

if(x>2.5){
   x2 = "X =" + Double.toString(x);
}

//How do I use the x2 outside the if function?
System.out.println(x2);
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but the other guy was first

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable in the scope you wish to use it, and *definitely assign* it through all paths to the usage. Definite assignability and reachability are defined in a non-human friendly fashion in the JLS, but developing "intuition" for it is relatively easy (except constant expressions in `if` statements [not a function]).

```
int x = 3;
final String x2;

if (x > 2.5) {
    x2 = "X =" + Double.toString(x);
} else {
    x2 = "X out of bounds";
}

System.out.println(x2);
```

(`final` indicates to reader and compiler that `x2` is only ever assigned once.)